# How could i create loop in PHP and keep track of its completeness

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple newsletter sending application using php. I was wondering if i could create a script in PHP which runs continuously even the browser is closed.

I have  written code as

```
<?php
        include "db.php";
        $newsletterid=$_GET['id'];
        $t="select * from tbl_newsletters where newsletterid='".$newsletterid."'";
        $q=mysql_query($t);
        $r=mysql_fetch_array($q);
        $Subject=$r['subject'];
        $Message=$r['message'];
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: '.$_SESSION['login_name'].'<'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: My Newsletter Manager <newsletter@myexample.com>' . "\r\n";

        $t="select email from tbl_subscribers where status='SUBSCRIBED'";
        $q=mysql_query($t);
        while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {
            $addresses[]=$r['email'];   
        }
        foreach($addresses as $address)
        {
            mail($address,$Subject,$Message,$headers) or die("Cannot Send Email");
            $t="insert into tbl_activities set
                username='".$_SESSION['login_name']."',
                activity='Sent News Letter [$Subject] to $address',
                date='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."',
                status='SUCCESS'                
                ";
            mysql_query($t) or die("Error Saving to Database");
        }

?>
```

I am a bit confident that this script works while sending newsletters to all subscribers but what will happen if the newsletter operator closed the browser. Will this script continuously send newsletters until the foreach loop is completed?

Even if this script works, i am willing to display a progress bar for each email sent which the operator can view any time he/she wishes.

Simultaneously I wish i could prevent the operator to re-send the newsletter until the previous one is completed?

I am not an expert and don't have advanced knowledge of OOP and Class instances?

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [PHP's Connection Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php). This section of the documentation talks about [ignore_user_abort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php), a function which tells the PHP interpreter to continue executing after the browser severs its connection with the PHP script.  It also tells you about [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), a function to set the timeout duration for the script.

For example, you might want to add code like this to your script:

```
set_time_limit( 0 ); // 0 means never timeout
ignore_user_abort(true); // continue running when browser closes
```

As your code runs outside of a connection with a browser, issues like error handling, memory management, and event logging become more important.  It's helpful to know if your code, running long after the browser went away, was successful, and what it actually did.

Instead of having your PHP code run after the browser connection is broken, another option to consider is to write the long-running code as a server-side process, and have the PHP script only invoke this server process. This means all the issues of error handling, memory mangement, and event logging can be handled in a server-side application programming environment, like Java, which might have better capabilities than PHP.

Comment: How can I create server side process using php? could you suggest me any link to learn or have a simple code snippet?

Comment: PHP code does run on the server, so a PHP script running after the user abort happens is "a server-side process". What I was suggesting was that you write the long-running code in a different language and environment, one better suited to the job. Which languages and frameworks to use for this is a large question, beyond the scope of your question here.

Answer (score 1):

What the script does when a user closes the client is dependent on how you deal with PHP's [connection handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php).  You can abort the script, or you can have it continue.

If you decide to abort the script, you can implement a function that can save the last email address the newsletter was sent to.  Optionally, you can write to a log file within the loop, and if the script gets aborted, you'll know all the emails that were already notified.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP interpreter imposes a time limit on scripts, and will terminate a script that runs for too long.  I think the default time limit is 30 seconds, though it can be changed in the server's configuration.

As far as I know, PHP scripts only run in response to requests from clients (e.g. a browser), and the script's purpose is just to respond to that specific request.  You can't do background processing, independent of any request.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple test code:

```
 <?php

set_time_limit(0);  //set time limit = unlimited

ini_set('memory_limit','900M'); //memory max 900MB


for($i=0;$i<=30000;$i++)
{
    file_put_contents('temp/'.$i.'.txt','Some data...');
}

?>
```

After open in browser, then i closed the browser again, PHP still processing my instruction, and success writing all txt files (0-30000). Maybe you can create your own testing using mail() function. Hope this simple test give your more idea.

Maybe you want to see how PHP connection status is maintained: [PHP Connection handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php).

Comment: I will try this code and will write more about the output i got

Comment: I tried with the same code you provided and it worked but there was another problem, The server didn't responded to other requests until this process was finished.

Comment: Can you check server resources while running this process?

Comment: I tried the code uploading to my webhost and their i found it worked. Maybe it caused server overloading while trying on XAMPP.